# Compiling Tesseract-OCR 3.01 for Objective C on MacOsX (Non iPhone)

Tags: objective-c, macos, compilation, ocr, tesseract

I want to implement the [Tesseract OCR library](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) in one of my Macintosh applications and I'm facing a problem which I feel like I can't solve by myself.

**I have to compile the files for Objective C for Mac development.** I was searching the web and every post I found was nearly 2 years old. I found some scripts (see code segment below) that where all for OLD iOs Versions and just replacing the iOs related paths by MacOsX related ones did not work.

I've never done something like this before. If you have a solution I would be really thankful, but if you can just give me hints on where to look it would be well appreciated either. I know that I shouldn't compile for the arm architecture, but there are so many codesegments where I don't know what I'm doing, that I need a bit of assistance...

Thanks in advance!

```
#!/bin/sh
# build_fat.sh
#
# Created by Robert Carlsen on 15.07.2009. Updated 24.9.2010
# build an arm / i386 lib of standard linux project
#
# initially configured for tesseract-ocr v2.0.4
# updated for tesseract prerelease v3
 
outdir=outdir
mkdir -p $outdir/arm $outdir/i386
 
libdirs=( api ccutil ccmain ccstruct classify cutil dict image textord training viewer wordrec )
libs=( api ccutil main ccstruct classify cutil dict image textord training viewer wordrec )
count=${#libdirs[@]}
 
make distclean
unset CPPFLAGS CFLAGS LDFLAGS CPP CXX CC CXXFLAGS DEVROOT SDKROOT LD
 
export DEVROOT=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
export SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk
export CPPFLAGS=”-I$SDKROOT/usr/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include/ -I$SDKROOT/usr/include/ -miphoneos-version-min=3.0″
export CFLAGS=”$CPPFLAGS -arch armv6 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT”
export LDFLAGS=”-L$SDKROOT/usr/lib/”
export CXXFLAGS=”$CFLAGS”
export CPP=”$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp-4.2 $CPPFLAGS”
export CXX=”$DEVROOT/usr/bin/g++-4.2 $CXXFLAGS”
export CC=”$DEVROOT/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 $CFLAGS”
./configure LD=$DEVROOT/usr/bin/ld –host=arm-apple-darwin
make -j4
cp api/.libs/libtesseract_api.a libtesseract_api_armv6.a
cp ccutil/.libs/libtesseract_ccutil.a libtesseract_ccutil_armv6.a
cp ccmain/.libs/libtesseract_main.a libtesseract_main_armv6.a
cp ccstruct/.libs/libtesseract_ccstruct.a libtesseract_ccstruct_armv6.a
cp classify/.libs/libtesseract_classify.a libtesseract_classify_armv6.a
cp cutil/.libs/libtesseract_cutil.a libtesseract_cutil_armv6.a
cp dict/.libs/libtesseract_dict.a libtesseract_dict_armv6.a
cp image/.libs/libtesseract_image.a libtesseract_image_armv6.a
cp textord/.libs/libtesseract_textord.a libtesseract_textord_armv6.a
cp training/.libs/libtesseract_training.a libtesseract_training_armv6.a
cp viewer/.libs/libtesseract_viewer.a libtesseract_viewer_armv6.a
cp wordrec/.libs/libtesseract_wordrec.a libtesseract_wordrec_armv6.a

make distclean
unset CPPFLAGS CFLAGS LDFLAGS CPP CXX CC CXXFLAGS DEVROOT SDKROOT
export CFLAGS=”-arch i386 -pipe -no-cpp-precomp”
export CXXFLAGS=”$CFLAGS”
./configure
make -j4
cp api/.libs/libtesseract_api.a libtesseract_api_i386.a
cp ccutil/.libs/libtesseract_ccutil.a libtesseract_ccutil_i386.a
cp ccmain/.libs/libtesseract_main.a libtesseract_main_i386.a
cp ccstruct/.libs/libtesseract_ccstruct.a libtesseract_ccstruct_i386.a
cp classify/.libs/libtesseract_classify.a libtesseract_classify_i386.a
cp cutil/.libs/libtesseract_cutil.a libtesseract_cutil_i386.a
cp dict/.libs/libtesseract_dict.a libtesseract_dict_i386.a
cp image/.libs/libtesseract_image.a libtesseract_image_i386.a
cp textord/.libs/libtesseract_textord.a libtesseract_textord_i386.a
cp training/.libs/libtesseract_training.a libtesseract_training_i386.a
cp viewer/.libs/libtesseract_viewer.a libtesseract_viewer_i386.a
cp wordrec/.libs/libtesseract_wordrec.a libtesseract_wordrec_i386.a

$DEVROOT/usr/bin/lipo -arch armv6 libtesseract_api_armv6.a -arch i386 libtesseract_api_i386.a -create -output libtesseract_api.a
$DEVROOT/usr/bin/lipo -arch armv6 libtesseract_ccutil_armv6.a -arch i386 libtesseract_ccutil_i386.a -create -output libtesseract_ccutil.a
$DEVROOT/usr/bin/lipo -arch armv6 libtesseract_main_armv6.a -arch i386 libtesseract_main_i386.a -create -output libtesseract_main.a
$DEVROOT/usr/bin/lipo -arch armv6 libtesseract_ccstruct_armv6.a -arch i386 libtesseract_ccstruct_i386.a -create -output libtesseract_ccstruct.a
$DEVROOT/usr/bin/lipo -arch armv6 libtesseract_classify_armv6.a -arch i386 libtesseract_classify_i386.a -create -output libtesseract_classify.a
$DEVROOT/usr/bin/lipo -arch armv6 libtesseract_cutil_armv6.a -arch i386 libtesseract_cutil_i386.a -create -output libtesseract_cutil.a
$DEVROOT/usr/bin/lipo -arch armv6 libtesseract_dict_armv6.a -arch i386 libtesseract_dict_i386.a -create -output libtesseract_dict.a
$DEVROOT/usr/bin/lipo -arch armv6 libtesseract_image_armv6.a -arch i386 libtesseract_image_i386.a -create -output libtesseract_image.a
$DEVROOT/usr/bin/lipo -arch armv6 libtesseract_textord_armv6.a -arch i386 libtesseract_textord_i386.a -create -output libtesseract_textord.a
$DEVROOT/usr/bin/lipo -arch armv6 libtesseract_training_armv6.a -arch i386 libtesseract_training_i386.a -create -output libtesseract_training.a
$DEVROOT/usr/bin/lipo -arch armv6 libtesseract_viewer_armv6.a -arch i386 libtesseract_viewer_i386.a -create -output libtesseract_viewer.a
$DEVROOT/usr/bin/lipo -arch armv6 libtesseract_wordrec_armv6.a -arch i386 libtesseract_wordrec_i386.a -create -output libtesseract_wordrec.a

unset CPPFLAGS CFLAGS LDFLAGS CPP CXX CC CXXFLAGS DEVROOT SDKROOT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent the last couple of days on this topic and I managed to compile a working library against **iOs SDK 5.0, 4.2 and for Simulator i386**.

These two tutorials helped me a LOT! Hope they'll help someone else too:

[how to: cross compiling libraries for ios (armv6/armv7/i386)](http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/how-to-cross-compiling-libraries-for-ios-armv6armv7i386/)

[how to: compile and use tesseract (3.01) on ios (sdk 5)](http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/)

I'm still trying to get those to work in the MacOsX environment though. If I manage to get it done I'll post again.

Comment: Yes I did. ;) But it’s the build from 2010. So most of the modern language.traineddata files don’t actually work… At the moment I’m just working with the english.traineddata file.

Comment: If it helps anyone else, I got tesseract to work on OSX using MacPorts

Comment: Did you get the framework to work or just the program you can access via the Terminal?

Comment: so far just the command via terminal. I've not had a chance to integrate it into any iOS program.

Comment: We are talking about OSX here. There are plenty of iOS projects on Github. :) Just search for “Tesseract iOS" over there. ;)